# What represents a STEP in Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, cloud, cluster-computing, google-cloud-build

Actually I am working on a pipeline, all good until there because it has worked. But when I want to explain it is not clear to me what each step represents physically, for example a step "could" be a node within a cluster.Please, if someone has a clear explanation of it, explain it to us.

- Example 1 of a step

File config cloud build:

```yaml
steps:
 - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
  args: ["bin/deploy-dags-composer.sh"]
  env:
    - 'COMPOSER_BUCKET=${_COMPOSER_BUCKET}'
    - 'ARTIFACTS_BUCKET=${_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET}'
  id: 'DEPLOY-DAGS-PLUGINS-DEPENDS-STEP'
```

Bash File

```sh
#! /bin/bash
gsutil cp bin/plugins/* gs://$COMPOSER_BUCKET/plugins/
gsutil cp bin/dependencies/* gs://$ARTIFACTS_BUCKET/dags/dependencies/
gsutil cp bin/dags/* gs://$COMPOSER_BUCKET/dags/
gsutil cp bin/sql-scripts/* gs://$ARTIFACTS_BUCKET/path/bin/sql-scripts/composer/
```

- Example 2 several steps

File config cloud build

```yaml
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ['cp', '*', 'gs://${_COMPOSER_BUCKET}/plugins/']
  dir: 'bin/plugins/'
  id: 'deploy-plugins-step'
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ['cp', '*', 'gs://${_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET}/dags/dependencies/']
  dir: 'bin/dependencies/'
  id: 'deploy-dependencies-step'
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ['cp', '*', 'gs://${_COMPOSER_BUCKET}/dags/']
  dir: 'bin/dags/'
  id: 'deploy-dags-step'
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ['cp', '*', 'gs://${_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET}/projects/path/bin/sql-scripts/composer/']
  dir: 'bin/sql-scripts/'
  id: 'deploy-scripts-step'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cloud Build, a step is a stage of the processing. This stage is described by a container to load, containing the required binaries for the processing to perform in the stage.

To this container, you can define an entrypoint, the binary to run in side the container, and args to pass to it.

You have also several option that you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config).

An important concept to understand is that ONLY the `/workspace` directory is kept from one step to another one. At the end of each step, the container is offloaded and you lost all the data in memory (like environment variable) and the data stored outside of the `/workspace` directory (such as system dependency installation). Keep this in mind, many of issues come from there.

---

EDIT 1:

In a step, you can, out of the box, run 1 command on one container. gsutil, gcloud, mvn, node,.... All depends on your container and your entrypoint.

But there is a useful advance capacity, when you need to run many commands on the same container. It can occur for many reason. You can do such like this

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        MY_ENV_VAR=$(curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance)
        echo $${MY_ENV_VAR} > env-var-save.file
        # Continue the commands that you need/want ....
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for u answer, then I could say that a step is equivalent to a command like for example `gsutil cp *.txt gs://my-bucket` ??

Comment: You can perform several actions in a step. In fact it's an environment context with pre installed binary, when you need another binary, change of steps and load another container.

Comment: Great. So, based on what you tell me, I could encapsulate several actions in a single step, in order to save processing charges or execution time charges. In my publication I leave you two examples, could you tell me if there is an impact between them? (either cheap or fast processing)

Comment: Even if the container are already in cache and you don't have to re download them (like in your second example), you still lost time in context switching. It's more efficient to have a script. It's a tradeoff in maintainability and efficiency

Comment: thank you for your help to understand cloud build a bit in depth, just to finish I would like you to recommend me a book or course on the subject thank you and happy holidays: D

Comment: Not especially book. I don't know good reference on Cloud Build especialy. I can just recommend you to test, test, and test, strange or abnormal things to go deeper and to understand better the capacity and the limits. And don't hesitate to ask more question here if you are blocked!!